# React useEffect behavior

Tags: reactjs

Having such a simple React component:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function useMediaQuery(query:string) {
    
    console.log("useMediaQuery")

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect outer")
        // ...
    });

}

const Sidebar: FunctionComponent = () => {

    const istoBeHidden = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 700px)')
    console.log("returned from useMediaQuery")
    useEffect(() => console.log("useEffect inner"))

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Sidebar</p>
            {/* <button onClick={myFunction}>Click me</button> */}
        </div>
    )
};

export {Sidebar}
```

I'm getting the following output in the console:

> useMediaQuery
> returned from useMediaQuery
> useEffect outer
> useEffect inner

My question is WHY does the `useEffect outer` is called AFTER returning from the
`useMediaQuery` function (why does the line `useEffect outer` appears AFTER the line `returned from useMediaQuer`y)!?

Comment: I think you can find direction here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 0):

We need a little bit of a background here to understand why it behaves like this.

As we all know React uses JSX, which produces a representation of DOM. It means all functions get called to produce it each time React decides to update. After that, another step takes place and all effects get evaluated. Effects are guaranteed to run after rendering.

Now, going back to your case.
In first phase, React calls your Sidebar function. All functions inside of it get executed, therefore you see logs in your console. After that, changes are committed and effects are called. That's why you see logs from the effects at the end.

Comment: So the `useMediaQuery` and `returned from useMediaQuery` are called when the browser creates a DOM elements (building the DOM tree) and `useEffect outer` and `useEffect inner` are always called later when the DOM creation is complete chance the are called last?

Comment: Sort of. As I said, React creates a representation of real DOM (VirtualDOM), then compares against previously generated one and apply changes to the real DOM. After that, effects are called.

Answer (score 0):

`useMediaQuery` is a hook inside a functional component. Custom hook is just a way to encapsulate some logic into a function, which might/might not use state.

The custom hook code runs on every render. But you cannot expect the hook to run all its useEffects and **get done with**. The useEffect inside the custom hook is just like any useEffect, it will run based on its dependency array.

It has no dependency array, so it will be called everytime there is a render, which happens every time the component rerenders.

```js
function useMediaQuery(query) {
    console.log("useMediaQuery")
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect outer")
    });

}

function App() {
    const istoBeHidden = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 700px)');
   const [count,setCount] =  React.useState(0);
    console.log("returned from useMediaQuery",count)
    React.useEffect(() => console.log("useEffect inner"))

    return (<div><button onClick={() => setCount(count => count+1)}>Sidebar</button></div>);
};


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: So concluding: the "outer" `useEffect` (that in the `useMediaQuery` function) is just the `Sidebar` component "property" just like the "inner" `useEffect` (defined in the component body itself) and both of them behaves similarly and are called every time the component re-renders?